# IOTA Tangle support in Zebra Savanna

Tags: zebra-savanna

​Does this platform provide anything related to barcode generator that can reflect something to IOTA Tangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Track & Trace Ledger APIs can be easily integrated with printing devices such as Zebra Printers. This means that whenever a Zebra Printer generates a new barcode or batch of barcodes a new event will be received by the API (similar to the scan or read events generated by readers or scanners) and a new transaction sent to the Tangle. Such transactions could be used later as a proof of existence and authenticity of a barcode or batch of barcodes.